# How to Set up BizTalk Services for receiving .JSON messages

Tags: json, azure, websocket, azure-sql-database, biztalk

I want to build a BizTalk Service that is able to receive .JSON messages via a Websocket (TLS) and also is able to forward the message to an SQL-Server.

Do I need SignalR?

Comment: SQL Azure, or on prem SQL Server?  You shouldn't need SignalR for this.  When you say Websocket, do you plan to use a ServiceBus Relay?  Hybrid Connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no first class support for JSON in BizTalk Service.  You will need to use Message Inspectors to achieve this.  The following blog post explains what needs to be done [[link]](http://blog.appliedis.com/2013/08/28/extending-windows-azure-biztalk-services-using-message-inspectors/)